# What do the colors mean in the output of `git branch -a`?

Tags: git

Four of the branches listed by `$ git branch -a` for a Git repository are colored in red in the terminal output.

The [Git configuration guide](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) has a section headed "Colors in Git" that doesn't explain what the "colors in git" mean, or provide a way to learn what they mean.

Web searches and searching Stack Overflow give no relevant results.

What do the colors in the terminal output of `git branch -a` mean?

Comment: Are they the `remotes/` branches, by any chance? Per [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---colorltwhengt): _"highlight current, local, and remote-tracking branches"_ (default seems to be green, white and red respectively).

Comment: @jonrsharpe They are, is that what the red means?  It really makes it look like there's some sort of error with my remotes.

Comment: Yes, that's what it means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colors are configurable—both whether they are used at all, and if so, which color has what meaning.  The *default* settings are:

- Use color if `git branch` output is going to a "terminal device".  That should make you ask the obvious question, *What the bleep is a terminal device?*  The obvious answer from the English language would be a device that kills you, but that's not it.  At least, we hope that's not it!

  In this case a "terminal device" is one for which `isatty`, in the C library, returns a truthful status.  That's still rather cryptic, but to go any further, we would have to know what OS and/or C library you are using.  On Linux-like systems, including macOS, these days, it mostly means "in a terminal window": something running Terminal or iTerm or xterm or one of the many other things that, indirectly, emulate an ancient printer from the late 1960s.  More precisely, they're emulating something emulating the VT100, which emulated the ADM3A, which—as a so-called "glass tty"—emulated the ASR33 and other similar printers.
- Use green for the *current branch;* use red for any *remote-tracking names;*<sup>1</sup> and use the default—whatever that is for your terminal emulator—for all remaining names.

This helps distinguish the current branch (standing out in green) and remote-tracking names (which, while listed by `git branch`, aren't really *branch* names, in an important way).  In particular, you cannot get "on" a remote-tracking branch the way you get "on" a (local) branch.  The word local in parentheses here is redundant: *all* branch names are local (see footnote 1 again).

---

<sup>1</sup>Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names*, using the word *branch* yet again in a way that just makes everything even more confusing.  A remote-tracking name, or remote-tracking branch name if you prefer Git's phrase here, is a name that exists locally *because* your Git software called up some other Git software, probably on some other machine, perhaps on GitHub for instance, and that *other* Git software said that they—the other machine with the other repository—have some particular branch name.

Your Git—by which I mean your software, running on *your* machine using *your* repository—takes their *branch* names and modifies them, so that they will be entirely separate from any of *your* branch names.  Your Git then stores the modified names—the remote-tracking names—in your own repository.  This lets your Git remember *their* Git's *branch* names, and corresponding commit hash IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Per [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---colorltwhengt), the branches are colored to "highlight" (differentiate) current, local, and remote-tracking branches.

Default (as of v2.39.1) is:
green - current
white - local
red - remote tracking